# Dynamic functions in sql - using IF

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a small question

```
 @CMD nvarchar (MAX)='' 
SELECT @CMD +=N'


 SELECT
     COUNT(CASE WHEN RFRD.QueuTypeID=4
           THEN RFRD.QueuTypeID
           END) RequiredaQueue
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN RFRD.QueuTypeID=3
          THEN RFRD.QueuTypeID
          END) BhinaQueue      
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN RFRD.QueuTypeID NOT IN (3,4) 
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT RFRD.LeadDocumentID)AS Repeat,CONCAT('''+RF+''' ,''*'')A'                                              
FROM #cte RF
```

p.s - The From is outside the dynamic.

Works fine here...
But when I add `IF` statement:

```
   SELECT
     COUNT(CASE WHEN RFRD.QueuTypeID=4
           THEN RFRD.QueuTypeID
           END) RequiredaQueue
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN RFRD.QueuTypeID=3
          THEN RFRD.QueuTypeID
          END) BhinaQueue      
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN RFRD.QueuTypeID NOT IN (3,4)'
     **IF @MyParam IS NOT NULL**
   SET @CMD+='
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT RFRD.LeadDocumentID)AS Repeat,CONCAT('''+RF+'''                                               ,''*'')A'                                              
FROM #cte RF
```

The program doesn't understand what is the `RF` means.
it doesn't see the `FROM #cte` RF Anymore.
any body knows whats the problem with the `IF` statement??
thanks

Comment: you forgot `then` in `if statement`

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande, it is not necessary

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Thanks dont know about it.

Comment: You have some messed up code. What are you trying to do?

Comment: In your post you are missing some brackets (`)`) and other syntax, please check with your real code.

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What exactly are you trying to acheive?

Comment: i new at the forum, i posed as an answer by a mistake... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then don't use `if`.  Use `case`:

```
 @CMD nvarchar (MAX)='' 

SELECT @CMD +=N'
 SELECT
     COUNT(CASE WHEN RFRD.QueuTypeID=4
           THEN RFRD.QueuTypeID
           END) as RequiredaQueue
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN RFRD.QueuTypeID=3
          THEN RFRD.QueuTypeID
          END) as BhinaQueue   
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN RFRD.QueuTypeID NOT IN (3,4) '
    (case when @MyParem is not null then ',COUNT(DISTINCT RFRD.LeadDocumentID)AS Repeat,CONCAT('''+RF+''' ,''*'')A' 
          else ''
     end)  + '                                           
FROM #cte RF ';
```

All the code is inside a `select` statement, so `case` is the appropriate construction, not `if`.